# Flutter fill available space in scroll view

Tags: flutter

In the following code I have a `SingleChildScrollView`, I used `ConstrainedBox` to set a `minHeight` for its content

I want to force blue content to fill available space, I cannot use `Expanded` because we are in scroll view, As I? set `minHeight` before we can determine the **available space** some how

Actually I want to set a `minHeight` constraint to blue container, here red container has `height: 500` but in real case it is unknown

- make blue container as big as possible if device height it big enough and we have no scroll
- it device height is not big enough, and we have scroll, set height of blue box as is (auto)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
                BoxConstraints(minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green[300],
                  height: 500,
                  child: Placeholder(),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[300],
                  child: Text('Expand me!'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap column with `IntrinsicHeight`.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use CustomScrollView with SliverFillRemaining passing hasScrollBody false. It's not necessary to use LayoutBuilder and IntrinsicHeight.

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green[300],
              height: 500,
              child: const Placeholder(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue[300],
                height: 100 //set your min height
                child: const Text('Expand me!'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```